# Set up of DD4T java with SDL Web 8

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, dd4t, web8

1. I have installed all the prerequisites expected in SDL Web 8 set up.

*Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit), 
*Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP2, 
*IIS 8.5 (included with Web Server role),
*Web Server role, Application Server role,
*Oracle Java 8, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2

2. Created databases by running associated scripts.

(i)Content Manager
(ii)Topology Manager
(iii)Content Data store
(iv)Experience Manager

3. Then installed SDLWeb8CM set up.

then i set up content delivery for single machine

---

deployer\,
discovery\,
preview\ &
session\

ran all the concerned scripts.

Installed Apache Tomcat 8.x

Now i am not able to figure out how to set up a java web app deployed inside Apache Tomcat with CD.

Comment: Welcome to tridion.stackexchange.com, Javed. This may be an obvious question, but have you gone through the DD4T documentation? It's hard to tell from your question exactly where you are stuck. If you can be more concrete, you have a better chance of getting a good answer.